# Track changes with specific set of opportunity within a specific period of time

Tags: opportunity-history

Would like to develop a report in SFDC based on a set of opportunities (Based on Top 25 Opportunity Amount or Specific set of Opportunities).
I would want to track the journey of these opportunity within a specific date range, egs starting Q1 till end of Q1 or compare between two different weeks etc